# Importing special characters from csv file

Tags: angular

I'm using the NgxCsvParser library with my Angular app.
I'm importing a csv file so:

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<input type="file" #csvReader name="Upload CSV" id="txtFileUpload" (change)="uploadListener($event)" accept=".csv" />
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
import { NgxCsvParser } from 'ngx-csv-parser';
constructor(private ngxCsvParser: NgxCsvParser) { }

uploadListener($event: any): void {

    let text = [];
    let files = $event.srcElement.files;

    if (this.isValidCSVFile(files[0])) {
      this.ngxCsvParser.parse(files[0], { header: false, delimiter: ',' })
      .pipe().subscribe((result: Array<any>) => {
 

        result.forEach(element => {
          let tempObject = {
            "id": element[0],
            "textToTranslate": element[1]
          }
          this.records.push(tempObject);
        });

        this.records.shift();

        //console.log('Result', result);
        //this.records = result;

        console.log(this.records);

      }, (error) => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
    } else {
      alert("Please import valid .csv file.");
      this.fileReset();
    }
  }
```

However if I'm importing special characters such as german like ä, they are being imported as squares. The font used to list out the imported values IS capable of displaying ä if I paste it into the DOM. So I'm assuming I need to amend something near `"textToTranslate": element[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [library source](https://github.com/tofiqquadri/ngx-csv-parser/blob/f00811049dbf4f404b42c8e37505070ae3a80b0d/projects/ngx-csv-parser/src/lib/ngx-csv-parser.service.ts#L29) you see it uses `FileReader.readAsText()` - this method can accept a 2nd `encoding` argument, however the library doesn't use that.

I would suggest modifying the library to include an option to specify encoding, and submit a pull request to it. In the mean time, you can fork the library and use your modified version.

It is possible to specify a [github repository](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#github-urls) as a library location in `package.json` in case you need to build on a remote CI/CD pipe.